# Why I can't I assign a value to an @State var in SwiftUI init?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why does this assignment to an @State var in init not work?

```
class getOldValuesFromDb : ObservableObject {
    @State var oldValue: Int = 0

    init(){
        let val = 999
        self.oldValue = val
        print("OldValue: \(self.oldValue) and Val: \(val)")
    }
}
```

The value for the `val` is displayed correctly, but as I assigned it to the `oldValue`, it still has a value of zero. My `print()` looks exactly like this:
`OldValue: 0 and Val: 999`
How it's possible?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem without all of the firebase jazz in the way? At the top of the init function,  `let val = 999`.  Assign val to self.oldValue and print.  What happens there will be an important clue

Comment: @danh Of course I can, but I'm not sure what you mean by "without all of the firebase jazz in the way". At the top of init() function I added ```var val = 999``` what else should I change?

Comment: I mean an altogether empty init function that doesn't depend on val coming from firebase.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to exactly should looks like.

Comment: I'm saying that this has something to do with SwiftUI and @State declaration and nothing to do with firebase.  if you try just `init(){ let val =999  self.oldValue = val    print("OldValue: \(self.oldValue) and Val: \(val)") }` You're apt to find the same odd print result.  I don't know how to fix the swift UI problem, but you should edit this question to focus on just that.  Nothing to do with firebase, IMO

Comment: That's right. Result is ```OldValue: 0 and Val: 999```. How we can fix it?

Comment: `@State` can only be used for `private` properties within a `View` type. I expect a compiler error should prevent you using it outside the `View`, if not now then probably soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that `@State` is supposed to be used outside of a `View`.

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state):

> SwiftUI manages the storage of any property you declare as a state. When the state value changes, the view invalidates its appearance and recomputes the body. Use the state as the single source of truth for a given view.

and

> You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body, or from methods called by it. For this reason, declare your state properties as private, to prevent clients of your view from accessing it. It is safe to mutate state properties from any thread.

Did you try using [@Published](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) instead ?